# Cannot switch on a value of type int[]. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted

Tags: java

**Cannot switch on a value of type int[]. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted**
**Can anyone help me with this issue??**

```
package first;

import java.util.Scanner;

class New {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int[] marks;
        marks = new int[] {29,32};

        switch (marks) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Sorry you are failed.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Sorry you didn't make it to the list.");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("I'm sorry result is negative.");
                break;
            case 29:
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You're Passed but got promoted.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Maybe you didn't appear for the exam.");
                break;
        }           
    }   
}
```

Comment: An array will never have a value of `29` (though it might *contain* `29`).  What are you actually trying to check here?

Comment: `marks` is a `int[]`. In switch you can not use it. you can use marks[0] or marks[1]

Comment: put the whole switch in a for loop... and instead of marks, switch on marks[i]

Answer (score 0):

Check the Oracle [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for data types which work with Switch. If you have to check for each specific value of the array then, you have to write a loop and check for each integer in the array as shown below,

```
for (int mark : marks) {
    switch (mark){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Sorry you are failed.");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Sorry you didn't make it to the list.");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("I'm sorry result is negative.");
            break;

        case 29:
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You're Passed but got promoted.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Maybe you didn't appear for the exam.");
            break;
    }
}
```